# Extjs on resize column width textfield Ui get destroyed

Tags: user-interface, extjs, gridpanel, column-width, vbox

Basically, the problem that I have is the following:

[image]

When I resize the column in my GridPanel the textbox UI near Name get destroyed: the line on the right disappear. It should instead resize according to the width. How could I fix it?

This is my code:

```
...
columns: {
    defaults: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    layout:'auto',
    items: [{
             text: Strings.sharedName,
             flex: 1,
             minWidth: Traccar.Style.columnWidthNormal,
             dataIndex: 'name',
             //style: 'text-align:right;!important',
             filter: 'string',
             defaults: {
                 margin: '-28 30 -5 50'
             },
             items: [{
                xtype: 'container',
                layout: {
                    type: 'vbox',
                    align: 'right'
                },
                flex: 2,
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    id: 'nameFilter',
                    listeners: {
                        change: function(field, value) {
                            filterGrid('name', value);
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }]
        }
...
```

Here a reproducible example:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3a41

Comment: You are adding the textfield to the header. You would need to reset the textfield width on resize on your own.

Comment: There are about 2-3 external plugins doing the job.

Comment: @Dinkheller can you mention some?

Comment: Take a look at these. Hope it helps.
https://github.com/jaykravetz/extjs-grid-filters  https://github.com/loiane/Ext.ux.grid.FilterBar

Comment: But most likely this problem happens because of the inline filter (instead of below each other)

Comment: Here is a fiddle including the first filter plugin: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3a7m